# Batch script importing certificate for all users

Tags: import, certificate

The below command adds a certificate to trusted root:

```
certutil.exe -addstore -f "root" "wienticket.cer"
```

But this seems to add the certificate only for the current user. What changes do I need to make to install it for all users ?